# Pushing the app to production on Heroku is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push the code to heroku but it is failing. The created app works fine on my computer but is failing when deployed to Heroku. I am using Rails version 6.1.6.1 in this deployment. Earlier, I created the same app using Rails version 7 and that got deployed flawlessly. I am new to this. I can see few warnings when pushing the code to Heroku. Please help what am I doing wrong.

```
D:\develop\rubyproject\alphablog>git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 607 bytes | 607.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.10
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.2
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.10
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Resolving dependencies.....
remote:        Using rake 13.0.6
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
remote:        Using minitest 5.16.2
remote:        Using zeitwerk 2.6.0
remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
remote:        Using erubi 1.11.0
remote:        Using racc 1.6.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.6
remote:        Using rack 2.2.4
remote:        Using nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Using marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Using msgpack 1.5.4
remote:        Using bundler 2.3.10
remote:        Using ffi 1.15.5
remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Using pg 1.4.2
remote:        Using thor 1.2.1
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.11
remote:        Using semantic_range 3.0.0
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.12.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 2.0.5
remote:        Using activesupport 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.13.8 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Using rack-test 2.0.2
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.13.0
remote:        Using puma 5.6.4
remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.7.2
remote:        Using sprockets 4.1.1
remote:        Using sassc 2.4.0
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using loofah 2.18.0
remote:        Using globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Using activemodel 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
remote:        Using activejob 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using activerecord 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using actionview 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using actionpack 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.11.5
remote:        Using actioncable 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using activestorage 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using railties 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Using actiontext 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using actionmailbox 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using webpacker 5.4.3
remote:        Using rails 6.1.6.1
remote:        Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (2.83s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.17
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        You don't have net-smtp installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
remote:        yarn install v1.22.17
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 15.60s.
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compiled all packs in /tmp/build_a9f44d06/public/packs
remote:        Hash: 964bd55ba6668af1f1c1
remote:        Version: webpack 4.46.0
remote:        Time: 3673ms
remote:        Built at: 08/09/2022 6:46:50 AM
remote:                                                Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
remote:               js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js   68.2 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  application
remote:            js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.br   15.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:            js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.gz   17.5 KiB          [emitted]
remote:           js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.map    204 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        application
remote:        js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.map.br   43.4 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.map.gz   50.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:                                        manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]
remote:                                     manifest.json.br  129 bytes          [emitted]
remote:                                     manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]
remote:        Entrypoint application = js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js js/application-4cb2b08e3c41888f7737.js.map
remote:        [3] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 480 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [4] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [5] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
remote:            + 3 hidden modules
remote:
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (23.49s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:        You don't have net-smtp installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 91.6M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v7
remote:        https://alphablogonr6.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: This app is using the Heroku-20 stack, however a newer stack is available.
remote: To upgrade to Heroku-22, see:
remote: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/alphablogonr6.git
   aaa1b45..55e9f84  main -> main
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is failing"? The command seems to finish successfully saying `... deployed to Heroku`

Comment: Note that Git has no role in accepting or rejecting here, it's just a transport system. And, as @KonstantinStrukov said, everything you've included here shows that it's all working just fine. You are getting several *warnings*, which you should fix, and a note that there's a newer Heroku stack available, which you might wish to investigate, but that's it.

Comment: Okay Thanks Torek and Konstantin. I will try and fix the warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is deployed just fine. But something about your application is throwing an error when you try to load the homepage.

Heroku is really friendly for checking the logs.

You can check the logs in your dashboard. The URL will be like this:
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/(yourappname)/logs

Or, install the [Heroku Command Line Interface](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
then from the console, within your project file, do this:
`heroku logs -t`

This will print out the server logs on your local console.

I'd bet a dollar that you actually forgot to perform a migration:

`heroku run rails db:migrate`

This is usually the thing I forget to do.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I did run the migrate command. The code was indeed correctly deployed. I checked the logs as you suggested and I did some more research on the error. I found that there was an issue with gem 'net-smtp' and I just had to require: false in the gem file. I think there is some version issue. I added require: false to the gemfile and ran bundle install and site is now live. Thank you so much! Here is the link to the site. https://alphablogonr6.herokuapp.com/